# Using React and axios for curl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, axios

Is it possible to make a `curl` request by using `axios`?

the curl string is:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' --data 'client_id=1234&client_secret=1234&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=bucket:create bucket:read data:write data:read viewables:read' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k | jq '.'
```

I tried to do this:

```
getToken() {

    axios.get({
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
        data: {
            client_id: '1234',
            client_secret: '1234',
            grant_type : 'client_credentials',
            scope: 'data:read data:viewables'
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        }, success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    })        
}
```

But with no luck - e.g. nothing happens.

I previously used the `cygwin`-terminal to make the `curl`-request and I succesfully got the response

```
{
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 1799,
 "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5X2RldiJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJjWTFqcm1rQXhPSVptbnNsOVhYN0puVURtVEVETGNGeCIsImV4cCI6MTQ4NzU2NzgwMSwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIl0sImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXV0b2Rlc2suY29tL2F1ZC9qd3RleHAzMCIsImp0aSI6InJZcEZZTURyemtMOWZ1ZFdKSVVlVkxucGNWT29BTDg0dFpKbXlmZ29ORW1MakF0YVVtWktRWU1lYUR2UGlnNGsifQ.uzNexXCeu4efGPKGGhHdKxoJDXHAzLb28B2nSjrq_ys"
}
```

So, is this possible with React/axios?

In addition to the question, can I pass the received token to another `curl` request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it's not really "a curl request". It's an HTTP request. Curl is just the tool you use to do HTTP (and other) actions via the command line.

In your HTTP request, I can see you're using `axios.get()`, however you're trying to do a post request (you've got a data object you're trying to send). So you should be using `axios.post()`. It'd be best to check out the [axios page](https://github.com/axios/axios) to see the syntax for HTTP posts, including how to include the data and header objects in the post.

In answer to your second question, yes you can. In the `.then()` section of your first axios post, you can do another axios post using the response, e.g.

```
axios.post(
    ...
).then(response => {
    // do another post with response.token or whatever as the data
})
...
```

Comment: ok good, thanks! :-) The url cannot be found though, I even tried with postman, but apparently there is no way through.

Comment: URL can't be found, like a 404 error? If it's the same copy/pasted URL between the curl and the axios post then I can't see how it'd be there with the curl request and 404 for the axios post.

Comment: yes its a 404 error :-/ My URL is: `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate&client_id=1234B&client_secret=1234&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:viewables` - am I missing something?

Comment: Well when you're doing the axios post the URL should just be `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate` and then you include the parameters in the `data` object. You don't include parameters in the URL for a post request, that's what you do for a get request.